# What is definate way to create HTML snippet page or template page to refresh it dynamically in Web Application using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to update table content without refreshing the whole html page. But whatever I try I get error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()".
Few times, I see no error, but also without the html parts that I want to load (html table or just simple div tag).
Here s ithe bound gsheet with apps script code + html pages.
https://docs.google.com/.../1YmPpsqVnBmLGLx8nW.../edit...
tableBody.html has simple tags for test. I wanted to load this simple html elements into my index.html page with Javascript/Jquery/Ajaz. After this trial, my intension is to load the table in tableDiv.html page in index.html dynamically when I want to load it (such as by click on a button).
Nothing seems working. I have tried all the answers from this https://stackoverflow.com/.../how-to-refresh-a-dynamic...
How are you experts doing this in 2021? Can please help me on this issue?

So, technically I need an answer to what is definate way to create HTML snippet page or template page to refresh it dynamically in  Web Application created using Google Apps Script? So, that when I want to replace a table with other table or a part of the page with other HTML prt, I can dynamiclly replace with respective html snippet content.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

testBuildTable() was just used to test the buildTable function.

gs:

```
function testBuildTable() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  buildTable({ row: 1, col: 1, numrows: vs.length, numcols: sh.getLastColumn(), ssid: ss.getId(), name: sh.getName() });
}
```

This is the real function and you can call it from google.script.run and it will return the html to the withSuccessHandler so that you can load it into a div with `document.getElementById().innerHTML = obj.hmtl`

```
function buildTable(obj) {
  const { row, col, numrows, numcols, ssid, name } = obj;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  const vs = sh.getRange(row, col, numrows, numcols).getDisplayValues();
  let html = '<style td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>';
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    html += '<tr>';
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        html += `<th>${c}</th>`
      } else {
        html += `<td>${c}</td>`
      }
    });
    html += '</tr>'
  });
  html += '</table>'
  obj.html = html;
  //Logger.log(html);
  return obj;
}
```

Possible js:

```
function loadDataInTable() {
  google.script.return
  .withSuccessHandler((obj) => document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = obj.html)
  .buildTable({row:1,col:1,numrows:'enter row',numcols:'enter cols',ssid:'id',name:'sheet name'});
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<style td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>COL1</th><th>COL2</th><th>COL3</th><th>COL4</th><th>COL5</th><th>COL6</th><th>COL7</th><th>COL8</th><th>COL9</th><th>COL10</th></tr><tr><td>15</td><td>14</td><td>7</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>7</td><td>9</td><td>18</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>9</td><td>19</td><td>11</td><td>10</td><td>6</td><td>4</td><td>19</td><td>3</td><td>14</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>5</td><td>16</td><td>7</td><td>12</td><td>12</td><td>12</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>0</td><td>18</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>11</td><td>15</td><td>4</td><td>6</td><td>15</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>14</td><td>18</td><td>11</td><td>13</td><td>19</td><td>12</td><td>1</td><td>15</td></tr><tr><td>19</td><td>18</td><td>18</td><td>7</td><td>19</td><td>3</td><td>17</td><td>15</td><td>11</td><td>0</td></tr></table>
```

Sheet1 Test Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 14 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 18 | 0 |
| 5 | 9 | 19 | 11 | 10 | 6 | 4 | 19 | 3 | 14 |
| 13 | 5 | 16 | 7 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 14 | 15 | 2 |
| 11 | 0 | 18 | 17 | 18 | 11 | 15 | 4 | 6 | 15 |
| 1 | 2 | 14 | 18 | 11 | 13 | 19 | 12 | 1 | 15 |
| 19 | 18 | 18 | 7 | 19 | 3 | 17 | 15 | 11 | 0 |

Comment: Thank you for your awsome response. I am able to use your code and create table in server side and return to client.